# Export a selection of environment variables with correct escaping

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, dash

I want to export some environment variables which I set in a dash script to a file:

```
myvariable="line 1

LINE=3
some characters: # \" \$
line 5"
myvariable2="abc"
export myvariable myvariable2
```

expected result (a usable script):

```
declare -x myvariable="line 1

LINE=3
some characters: # \" \$
line 5"
declare -x myvariable2="abc"
```

The result is what I get using the `export` command. But it exports all envvars and doesn't allow filtering. Because of the multi-line character of the variable, `grep`ing the result is not possible.

In contrast, the `printenv` command allow to output only a selection of variables, but it doesn't care about escaping and it doesn't output the variable names in this use case.

Comment: What kind of output do you expect to see? `export` and `printenv` are both returning your variables as you defined them. Did you want newlines to be converted to something else?

Comment: The output should be a usable script. `printenv` will create garbage, `printenv myvariable myvariable2` doesn't output a script, export exports the full environment including `PATH` etc and not only `myvariable` and `myvariable2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `zsh` or `yash`.

```
export -p myvariable myvariable2
```

would work as you'd expect.

Otherwise, in `bash`, you can still do:

```
for var in myvariable myvariable2; do
  printf 'export %s=%q\n' "$var" "${!var}"
done
```

POSIXly, you can do the quoting by hand using `awk`:

```
awk -v q="'" '
  function escape(v) {
    gsub(q, q "\\" q q, v)
    return q v q
  }
  BEGIN {
    for (i = 1; i < ARGC; i++)
      print "export " ARGV[i] "=" escape(ENVIRON[ARGV[i]])
  }' myvariable myvariable2
```

For fun, a hacky solution that works in some shells (`bash`, `zsh`, `mksh`, `ksh93`, not `yash` nor `dash`):

```
 (PS4=; set -x; export "myvariable=$myvariable") 2>&1
```

Comment: Nice answer. I use awk in my script because it's dash and moving to zsh is not an option. I'm a bit disappointed of bash/dash. Maybe I should really consider switching to another shell...