# Dash print expanded commands

Tags: shell, dash, set

Running *xtrace* or *set -x* with Bash will print the expanded command:

```
$ bash -xc 'touch "alfa bravo"'
+ touch 'alfa bravo'
```

However Dash does not print the command that is actually run:

```
$ dash -xc 'touch "alfa bravo"'
+ touch alfa bravo
```

The printed command appears to create 2 files, while the command actually
creates 1. Can Dash be made to print the commands that are actually run?

Comment: You can't! `dash` print expanded string under `-x` effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty awful workaround, but seems to do the trick:

```
BEGIN {
  w = "\47"
  while (++i < ARGC) {
    x = split(ARGV[i], y, w)
    for (each in y) {
      if (y[each] ~ /[^[:alnum:]%+,./:=@_-]/)
        printf w y[each] w
      else
        printf y[each]
      if (each < x)
        printf "\\" w
    }
    if (i == ARGC - 1)
      printf RS
    else
      printf FS
  }
}
```

Result:

```
$ awk -f charlie.awk touch "alfa bravo"
touch 'alfa bravo'

$ awk -f charlie.awk touch 'alfa"bravo'
touch 'alfa"bravo'

$ awk -f charlie.awk touch "alfa'bravo"
touch alfa\'bravo
```

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/234059/38906

Comment: @cuonglm thanks, but his solution is weird if the last character is a single quote `"alfa'"` -> `'alfa'\'''`

Comment: You can reuse that string for shell. It's weird for human, but good for the shell.

Comment: @cuonglm I just noticed, Bash does the same thing: `bash -xc "touch alfa\'"` -> `touch 'alfa'\'''`